# libreoffice how to digitally sign pdf export with gpg key

Tags: pdf, libreoffice, gnupg

I am trying to export as a pdf and add a signature, or add a signature to an existing pdf, but whenever I try to export, after selecting a gpg key to use for the certificate (I don't fill in any of the fields) I get an error on saving the file

[image: PDF export Signature generation failed]

Followed by another error

[image: General input/output error]

What should I be doing differently to prevent this error?

Comment: This seems a known bug: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=129030

Comment: @FrancescoFrassinelli good find